# Refactor jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-float

I am using the datepicker plugin from [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/) - The example is on the bottom of the page.

It is utilizing jquery animate() like this:

```
$('#widgetField>a').bind('click', function(){
    $('#widgetCalendar').stop().animate({height: state ? 0 : $('#widgetCalendar div.datepicker').get(0).offsetHeight}, 500);
    state = !state;
    return false;
});
```

I need a recommendation on how to refactor this into an accordian-like expanding div. I do not want the calendar to float, I need it to push the div content below it down.

Recommendations?

Comment: have you checked into jquery ui - would give you both native datepicker and accordion expanding div

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I am seeing the exact same problem.  I cannot have a floating div.  The content that is directly below the calendar needs to be pushed down.... The z-index on that calendar as well causes it to float...

Comment: retagged as with css, this is the main issue here

Comment: alonisser - doesn't the animate create the css that does this? Or am I wrong?

Comment: can you post the html of your page - I don't think we fully understand your problem. and specifically the html and css of the relevant parts of the page. and yes - this is  a css problem. which has to do with the widget css and the div underneath css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The widget floats because it has a position:absolute; and a height offset in the jquery function.

See the css:

`#widgetCalendar` has a style, position:absolute. You will need to remove that, which will make it work, but then there are additional styling issues that can all be taken care of with css adjustments.

Or, you can try using jQuery .slidedown:

```
 $('#widgetCalendar').slideDown();
```

Then you wouldn't need the height offset.

It would be great if you could do a jsfiddle, as I am unable to test without seeing what you are doing.

**Edited - user not using jQuery UI**

This is due to the nature of jquery UI - the calendar is a specialized dialog. The jQuery UI dialog is a popin. But, you can counteract this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay.  Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input.

Comment: Nope ... arrrggg :D May need to put it up in jfiddle for you ... but that is going to be challenging in of itself.

Comment: @chrislovecnm If you can put it in a fiddle, that would be great - or give a link to the page where you are using it

Comment: I ended up using it as a flat calendar and placing it in a div that I show hide.